# Cannot create new service with xinetd in RHEL6

Tags: centos, rhel, tcp, nagios, xinetd

I've installed the Nagios on My RHEL 6.4(x64) machine. and i added one more module name called "NSCA" for some central monitoring solution.so the setup required add **NSCA** service detail under **xinetd**.

I've installed the **xinetd** package using yum on RHEL6 server.

I added the NSCA file under ***/etc/xinet.d*** directory as per the setup. find the below,

```
# default: on
# description: NSCA (Nagios Service Check Acceptor)
service nsca
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        group           = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nsca
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/nsca.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 129.221.8.95
}
```

also I added port detail in ***/etc/service*** like below

```
nsca            5667/tcp                # NSCA
```

when I restart the ***xinetd*** service, I'm getting following error message in **/var/log/message** like below,

```
Aug  7 11:52:54 rhel6 xinetd[13140]: Reading included configuration file: /etc/xinetd.d/nsca [file=/etc/xinetd.d/nsca] [line=67]
Aug  7 11:52:54 rhel6 xinetd[13140]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = nsca
Aug  7 11:52:54 rhel6 xinetd[13140]: Service nsca failed to start and is deactivated.
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

> bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = nsca

indicates that the port (5667) is already in use.

Check if **nsca** is already running. Try `netstat -tuan` to see if anything else has the port in use. Verify that there is no copy of the nsca file in **/etc/xinet.d** so that xinetd is trying to start it twice.

Comment: Thanks @dor bro,
before posting here i've checked for **/etc/xinet.d** for duplicate, anyway there is no duplicate.

also checked **netstat -aunt | grep 5667** it gives what i expect like below,
`tcp        0      0 :::5667                   :::*                        LISTEN`

Finally, i reboot the RHEL server.

After rebooting its working working like charm, How COME?

Comment: For example,you could have already tried launching the said NCSA manually, and then, after the *xinetd* restart, there was an attempt to create a duplicate. Or it might have been some other process using the same port (this is less likely, but still possible).